# HTML5 Canvas steam effect not displaying correctly without a canvas fill

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I looking to have my Canvas steam effect to overlay the rest of my page content, but if I don't give the canvas a fill it displays the steam in a posterised way.

Un-commenting lines 24 & 25 will fill the canvas and the steam displays as expected.

```
c.fillStyle = '#000';
c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
```

Full demo on snippet below.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = canvas.width = 800;
var h = canvas.height = 700;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://wightfield.com/_temp/smoke_600-60.png";
var position = {x : 450, y : 410};
var mugPosition = {x : w/3, y : 500};

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var particles = [];
var random = function(min, max){
  return Math.random()*(max-min)*min;
};

var draw = function(){
  position.x;
  position.y; 
  var p = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
  particles.push(p);
  while(particles.length > 500) particles.shift();
  
  //c.fillStyle = '#000';
  //c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
  {
    particles[i].update();
  }
};
// generates the smoke particles
function Particle(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.velX = (random(1, 10)-5)/10;
  // distance of vertical travel
  this.velY = -9;
  this.size = random(3, 6)/10;
  this.alpha = 0.4;
  this.update = function(){
    this.y += this.velY;
    this.x += this.velX;
    this.velY *= 0.99;
    if(this.alpha < 0)
      this.alpha = 0;
    c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    c.save();
    c.translate(this.x, this.y);
    c.scale(this.size, this.size);
    
    c.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2);
    c.restore();
    this.alpha *= 0.90;
    this.size += 0.015;//
  };
}

setInterval(draw, 800/16);
```

```css
body{
  background:green;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the steam effect with no canvas fill color?

Comment: Use `ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)` rather than fillRect and you then get the transparent canvas you want.

Comment: Not sure what that's doing but it works a treat! Thank you.

Comment: I will put an answer as you have a few bits that could do with an change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h)` to get the transparent background you want.

I have also made some changes.

You where creating a new particle every frame, this will incure a lot of GC over time. Better to reset an existing particle so I added a reset function to the particles and add new particles then just reset them via a counter.

Your setting the transform was inefficient so I added a quicker way by directly setting the transform. Now you don't have to save and restore the canvas state for each particle, which can be slow on many machines/devices.

I have also made a check for a alpha value that is too low for anything to display and not draw the image, saving a little time

Rather than use `setInterval` which is just a bug without a cause waiting for a slow machine to be a pain. I have added `requestAnimationFrame` that will give a nice smooth 60Fps synced to the screen refresh and browser rendering.

Update.

Just realized that the number of particles can be reduced to fit the how many frames it will take for a particles alpha to go below the threshold of `c = 1/255` (c for cutoff).

You always start the alpha at `a = 0.4` and the rate of decay is `d = 0.9` If you consider each frame step as time `t` then it can be expressed as `ctx.alpha = a * Math.pow(d ,t)`

So if we want the number of frames until the alpha value is below `c` we need to solve `alpha = a*Math.pow(d,t)-c` for t which is `t = Math.log(c/a)/Math.log(d)`

The result for the decay you have is 44 so you were wasting 456 array entries.

Update #2

I have updated the answer to include image loading which I missed befor. You can find all the details in the script below as I have commented all that I have added and changed.

```js
"use strict"; // this is a javascript directive and must be on the first line of the 
              // script (if included but is not a requirement). 
              // It forces a more code run under more stringent rules. The advantages
              // are many, including making the code run faster.

var imageLoadCount = 0;  // counts the number of image loading, counts down as they load
var readyToAnimate = false; // flag to indicate that resources are available
// image indexes in images array to get correct images in the animation.
const PARTICLE_IMAGE_INDEX = 0;
const BACKGROUND_IMAGE_INDEX = 1;
var images = []; // an array of images 
// What follows is a self evoking function, this will isolate the loading stuff from the
// rest of the script as it is only needed once at start so no point keeping references to it all
// the self invoking function is
//  (function(){...code body})()
// the () at the end forces javascript to run what is inside the () before it.
(function (){        
    function imageLoaded(){ // image onload function "this" is a reference to the image
        imageLoadCount -= 1; // count the loaded image
        // if the count is zero all images have loaded
        if(imageLoadCount === 0){
            readyToAnimate = true;
        }
    }
    // a list of image urls that need to be loaded. 
    const imageURLs = [
        "http://wightfield.com/_temp/smoke_600-60.png",
        "http://wightfield.com/_temp/smoke_600-60.png", // repeating the image just as example
    ];
    imageURLs.forEach(function(url){  // for each image url start the load process
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        img.onload = imageLoaded; // set the image onload function
        imageLoadCount += 1;  // count the number of images loading
        images.push(img); 
    });
})();  // run the function
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var w = canvas.width = 800;
var h = canvas.height = 700;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');   
document.body.appendChild(canvas);    

var position = {
    x : 450,
    y : 410
};
var mugPosition = {
    x : w / 3,
    y : 500
};


var particles = [];
var random = function (min, max) {
    // YOU had Math.random() * (max - min) * min; I assume you did not want to multiply by min
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var particleCount = 0;
const ALPHA_CUTOFF = 1/255;
const ALPHA_START = 0.4;
const ALPHA_DECAY = 0.9
// calculate the number of particles need to show each step of the alpha decay
const MAX_PARTICLES = Math.ceil(Math.log(ALPHA_CUTOFF / ALPHA_START) / Math.log(ALPHA_DECAY));
console.log(MAX_PARTICLES)

var draw = function () {
    var i;
    if(readyToAnimate){  // wait for the resources to load 
        c.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform         
        c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        // If you want to render a background image do it here. If the image is the size of the
        // canvas then there is no need to clear the canvas and you can delete the line above
        /*  As an example
        c.drawImage(images[BACKGROUND_IMAGE_INDEX],0,0,w,h); // draws image filling the canvas
        */
        if (particles[particleCount % MAX_PARTICLES] === undefined) {
            particles[particleCount % MAX_PARTICLES] = new Particle(position.x, position.y);
        } else {
            particles[particleCount % MAX_PARTICLES].reset(position.x, position.y);
        }
        particleCount += 1;

        for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particles[i].update();
        }
    }else{
        // if you wanted you can add loading progress here
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};


function Particle(x, y) {
    this.reset(x, y);
}
Particle.prototype = {
    reset : function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = (random(1, 10) - 5) / 10;
        this.velY = -9;
        this.size = random(3, 6) / 10;
        this.alpha = ALPHA_START ;
        this.image = images[PARTICLE_IMAGE_INDEX];
    },
    update : function () {
        if(this.alpha >= ALPHA_CUTOFF ){  // no point in rendering a invisible sprite
            this.y += this.velY;
            this.x += this.velX;
            this.velY *= 0.99;            
            c.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
            c.setTransform(this.size,0,0,this.size,this.x, this.y);
            c.drawImage(this.image, -this.image.width / 2, -this.image.height / 2);
            this.alpha *= ALPHA_DECAY ;
            this.size += 0.015; //
        }
    }
}
// start the animation. Images may not have loaded yet
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer! It's running much more efficiently now. The only query I have is how do I add another static PNG  (https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2012/04/18/03/11/coffee-36726_960_720.png) to the canvas behind the steam effect without getting it constantly redrawn by adding it to the draw function?

Comment: @PaulBenbow If you want a background image you will have to render it each frame before you render the particles. I just noticed that you load the image but do not check if it has loaded. You should not start the animation until the image/s have loaded as there can be a delay between setting the image.src and the image being ready. I will modify my answer to show how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you for the update. When I show the background image and don't use c.clearRect(0, 0, w, h); I get the original posterized issue I had and if I do use clearRect the background flashes. Is there a way to keep the background static?

Comment: @PaulBenbow The background flashes???? that is odd.. Oh I know what it is, I left it out befor as you were just clearing the canvas, but now you have an image it will be rendered with the last particles alpha. In the draw function just after the line `c.setTransform(..` and before drawing the background image add `c.globalAlpha = 1;` this will stop the flashing

Comment: That works a treat. Thank you for all your assistance, I've learnt a lot!